# A __construct on an Eloquent Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a custom setter that I'm running in a `__construct` method on my model.

This is the property I'm wanting to set.

```
    protected $directory;
```

My Constructor

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->directory = $this->setDirectory();
    }
```

The setter:

```
    public function setDirectory()
    {
        if(!is_null($this->student_id)){
            return $this->student_id;
        }else{
            return 'applicant_' . $this->applicant_id;
        }
    }
```

My problem is that inside my setter the, `$this->student_id` (which is an attribute of the model being pulled from the database) is returning `null`.
When I `dd($this)` from inside my setter, I notice that my `#attributes:[]` is an empty array. 
 So, a model's attributes aren't set until after `__construct()` is fired. How can I set my `$directory` attribute in my construct method?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You need to change your constructor to:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    $this->directory = $this->setDirectory();
}
```

The first line (`parent::__construct()`) will run the Eloquent `Model`'s own construct method before your code runs, which will set up all the attributes for you. Also the change to the constructor's method signature is to continue supporting the usage that Laravel expects: `$model = new Post(['id' => 5, 'title' => 'My Post']);`

The rule of thumb really is to always remember, when extending a class, to check that you're not overriding an existing method so that it no longer runs (this is especially important with the magic `__construct`, `__get`, etc. methods). You can check the source of the original file to see if it includes the method you're defining.

Comment: This won't help, you will have empty array in $attributes. The model loads data later, not on constructor stage. See answer below (by Jed Lynch).

Comment: Bit late responding to your comment @Mike but FWIW this answer was from back in 2015 (if you can believe it!) and I believe it was correct at the time, even if in 2020+ there's now a better way. I've since moved on from Laravel so can't say one way of another on that. I wonder if there's a way to mark answers as "correct at the time but now outdated" in SO...

Answer (score 11):

I wouldn't ever use a constructor in eloquent.  Eloquent has ways to accomplished what you want.  I would used a [boot](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/providers#the-boot-method) method with an event listener.  It would look something like this.

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::retrieved(function($model){
         $model->directory = $model->student_id ?? 'applicant_' . $model->applicant_id;
    });
}
```

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events) are all the model events you can use: `retrieved`, `creating`, `created`, `updating`, `updated`, `saving`, `saved`, `deleting`, `deleted`, `trashed`, `forceDeleted`, `restoring`, `restored`, and `replicating`.

Comment: A little [more information](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events) on the events

Comment: As far as I can tell, retrieved is called before relationships are loaded.