# Create construct function for Eloquent Model Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this code

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use Stevebauman\Location\Drivers\Driver;
use Stevebauman\Location\Exceptions\DriverDoesNotExistException;

Class CRUD extends Eloquent {
protected $collection;
   public function __construct($collection ,array $attributes = array())
   {

  parent::__construct($attributes);

       $this->collection = $collection;

   }

}
```

when I am using this code in order to call the constructor , I get nothings
 $device_mode=new CRUD('HW101950054393');
because as I noticed when I trying to echo the $collection variable inside the constructor I get this error

> Array to string conversion

I don't understand that as I am passing the variable as string but the model working with it as array. 
why is that happening, and how can I solve it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A \_\_construct on an Eloquent Laravel Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502922/a-construct-on-an-eloquent-laravel-model)

Comment: No  that is not my answer

Comment: Do you have the namespace in your `CRUD` class file?

Comment: I tried your code and it should be working.

Comment: yes I have , namespace App;

Comment: What if you use `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;` instead of Jenssegers package, is this working?

Comment: No it is not working ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207590/discussion-between-m-bwe-and-adam).

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. Double check your if code is identical to what you posted.

I am using Laravel 5.6 and this is working without problems:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model
{
    protected $collection;

    public function __construct($collection, array $attributes = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $this->collection = $collection;
    }
}
```

Calling

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $test = new \App\Test('1234');
}
```

works fine.

Comment: @M.Bwe I added how I called the test class. I simply added a route and called it though browser `mydomain.dev/test`

Comment: ok , thank u , Still not working for me , thank you for your help

Comment: when I am using this code in order to call the constructor , I get nothings
 $device_mode=new CRUD('HW101950054393');
because as I noticed when I trying to echo the $collection variable inside the constructor I get this error 

> Array to string conversion

I don't understand that as I am passing the variable as string but the model working with it as array. 
why is that happening, and how can I solve it

Comment: @M.Bwe not sure, maybe collection name is used in `Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model`. You could try to rename your attribut `collection` to `test` or something

Comment: @M.Bwe, you cant echo an array, use `var_dump` or `dd` (stops execution immediately) to see their content safely.

Comment: @Adam I changed the name from collection to test , but when I write echo $test , the result is   HW101950054393Array which is mix of string and array even I called it using this command  $device_mode=new CRUD('HW101950054393')  which is only string