# App\Models\Order, string given, called in /home/delivery/public_html/laravel_application/app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel, I have a little difficulty. Is giving this error does anyone know how to fix?

```
 <?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Order;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class OrderChangedEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    /**
     * @var Order
     */
    public $order;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        //
          $this->order = $order;
    }
}
```

"Argument 1 passed to App\Events\OrderChangedEvent::__construct() must be an instance of App\Models\Order, string given, called in /home/delivery/public_html/lar ▶"

Comment: how are you dispatching this event? can you please share that code.

Comment: I believe you are passing wrong parameter from the controller. The constructor is expecting for an Order, but you are passing a string. There is another problem in your constructor, you need to include the Model's  own constructor method. Please refer to this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30503372/7882426

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does it look like from where you are triggering this event?

It should look like:

```
...

event(new OrderChangedEvent($order));
...
```

And `$order` needs to be an instance of the model `Order` then passed. For example:

```
$order = Order::findOrFail($id);

...

event(new OrderChangedEvent($order));
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved it for me!