# Laravel - Factory does not recognized fields in definition method

Tags: laravel

I just created a factory in order to run some tests:

CategoryFactory.php

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Category>
 */
class CategoryFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            //
            'company_id' => 1,
            'name' => fake()->name(),
            'parent_id' => null
        ];
    }
}
```

And added it to the model:

Category.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

use App\Scopes\CompanyScope;

class Category extends Model
{
    //
    use SoftDeletes, HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'company_id',
        'name',
        'parent_id'
    ];

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    if(isset(auth()->user()->company_id)) {
        $this->attributes['company_id'] = auth()->user()->company_id;
    }
}


protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope(new CompanyScope);
}
```

My test file looks like this:

```
public function test_category_edit_can_be_redered(): void
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create();
        $category = Category::factory()->create();

        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('/devices/categories/1/edit');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

But when I try to run the test, I get the following error:

```
General error: 1364 Field 'company_id' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `categories` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2023-08-08 01:55:43, 2023-08-08 01:55:43))
```

It looks like the definition in the factory is not being applied to the create method... Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: First look at the relationships of your user model. Is there a relationship to the category model?

Comment: @UnderDog no, but I have a boot and a construct and it seems to be the problem! check if you can help me! I have added to my question

Comment: @UnderDog I think is the construct that is resetting all the atributes

Comment: @UnderDog https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69993946/laravel-factory-fails-when-the-model-has-a-constructor found the answer here... the issue whats the constructor

Answer (score 2):

You trigger your category before you signIn a user so that the code doesn't have a default `auth()->user()`

Your code trigger a global scope event which is overriding the default `company_id`

you can use `use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents` or [saveQuietly()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#muting-events) in your seeder to not trigger global scope events.

You can also do this I think:

```php
public function test_category_edit_can_be_redered(): void
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create();
        Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
        $category = Category::factory()->create();

        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('/devices/categories/1/edit');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

Comment: no, this is wrong! the issue is in the link I passed below that for some reason was downvoted

Comment: I don't know why you are using constructor, when you can use `Observer` and `GlobalScope`. Especially when you're using laravel eloquent. It defeat the purpose instead of `model -> database` you're doing `model -> repository -> model -> database`