# Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $prevCart ]] in class App\Models\Cart

Tags: php

been having issues with my cart model. seem not to find where the error is coming from. it keeps returning  'Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $prevCart ]] in class App\Models\Cart' please I need help.[my Cart Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKc1G.png)

`<?php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class Cart extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $items;
    public $totalQuantity;
    public $totalPrice;


    public function __construct($prevCart){
        if($prevCart !=null){
                $this->items = $prevCart->items;
                $this->totalQuantity = $prevCart->totalQuantity;
                $this->totalPrice = $prevCart->totalPrice;
        }else{
            $this->items = [];
            $this->totalQuantity = 0;
            $this->totalPrice = 0;
        }
    }

    public function addItem($unique_id, $product){


        $price = (int) str_replace('$', '', $product->price);

        //if product already exists
        if(array_key_exists($unique_id, $this->items)){
            $productToAdd = $this->items[$unique_id];
            $productToAdd['quantity']++;

 
        }else{
            $productToAdd = ['quantity'=>0, 'price'=> $price, 'data'=>$product];
        }

         $productToAdd = $this->items[$unique_id];
         $this->totalQuantity++;
         $this->totalPrice = $this->totalPrice + $price;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Avoid using `__construct` with eloquent, maybe use a fluent setter instead. If you really want to use a constructor follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502922/a-construct-on-an-eloquent-laravel-model

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.